# Recyclerview findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition is not correct?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, linearlayoutmanager

Since I addData, and called the notifyDataSetChanged(), then I use the findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition method immediately, the result is not correct.then I use a postDelay, it's result become correct, why can this be? And how can i know whether the data added completely?

Comment: this is because the real job is done not in `notifyDataSetChanged` - this is just used to notify, you dont have to use `postDelayed`, use simple `post` instead

Comment: @pskink How were you able to find any error in this?! This is just text with (for me) seemingly random commands thrown in... Respect for that!

Comment: Still incredible. It is hard for me to understand source (without beeing formatted).

Comment: @pskink post sometimes not correct too, I've tested for several times

Answer (score 0):

Before adding the data to list, save Last visible position to a variable then add data to list and call notifyDataSetChanged(), then scroll the recyclerview to stored position

Comment: I get the data from net the first time, and I want to know if it is full page, but seems the visible item calculate is not immediate.

Comment: nothing special,  just add data(empty at the beginning), notify and findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition, but my item bean is a little complex, I think this may be the reason?